# Exclude category from /RSS feeds list

Tags: magento-1.9, category, rss

I have enabled **RSS** in `System > Configuration > RSS Feeds > Catalog > Top Level Category-->Enabled`.

However it lists **static pages** as well as **product categories** when I go to `www.mysite.com/rss`

*Is there way I can unlist category from RSS feeds list somehow?*

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Magento.SE!

The easiest approach here is to filter it to include only the categories you want. So create a new Magento plugin and rewrite the class `Mage_Rss_Block_List` in the file `/app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Block/List.php`.

Override the `CategoriesRssFeed` method with the following:

```
public function CategoriesRssFeed()
{
    $path = self::XML_PATH_RSS_METHODS.'/catalog/category';
    if((bool)Mage::getStoreConfig($path)){
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');

        /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Collection */
        $treeModel = $category->getTreeModel()->loadNode(Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
        $nodes = $treeModel->loadChildren()->getChildren();

        $nodeIds = array();
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            $nodeIds[] = $node->getId();
        }

        //filter the ids I don't want (e.g. category with id 23):
        $nodeIds = array_diff($nodeIds,array(23));

        $collection = $category->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('is_anchor')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active',1)
            ->addIdFilter($nodeIds)
            ->addAttributeToSort('name')
            ->load();

        foreach ($collection as $category) {
            $this->addRssFeed('rss/catalog/category', $category->getName(),array('cid'=>$category->getId()));
        }
    }
}
```